# How to rotate a complex Gradient Background?

Tags: html, css

I currently have this line of code:

```
background: linear-gradient(to left, #1e5799, #2ce0bf, #76dd2c, #dba62b, #e02cbf, #1e5799);
```

Right now I think the degree is 90, is there a way that I can modify that line of code to rotate the gradient? Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes,... `linear-gradient(-45deg, #1e5799, #2ce0bf, #76dd2c, #dba62b, #e02cbf, #1e5799);`

Answer (score 0):

```
 background: linear-gradient(180deg, #1e5799, #2ce0bf, #76dd2c, #dba62b,
```

Here is a practical example (ensure you use prefixes for cross borwser compatabiblity)

```css
#d {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(180deg, #1e5799, #2ce0bf, #76dd2c, #dba62b, #e02cbf, #1e5799);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, #1e5799, #2ce0bf, #76dd2c, #dba62b, #e02cbf, #1e5799);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(180deg, #1e5799, #2ce0bf, #76dd2c, #dba62b, #e02cbf, #1e5799);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #1e5799, #2ce0bf, #76dd2c, #dba62b, #e02cbf, #1e5799);
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="d"></div>
```

Comment: Always put prefixed properties first